# Replacing 0 values with NA in data.frame conditionally

Tags: r

```
dat <- data.frame(A=c("name1", "name2", "name3"), 
                  B=c(0,1,0), C=c(0,0,5), D= c(4,4,0), E=c(1,0,0), F=c(4,0,0) )

desiredresult <- data.frame(A=c("name1", "name2", "name3"), 
                            B=c(NA,1,NA), C=c(NA,0,5), D= c(4,4,0), E=c(1,0,NA), F=c(4,NA,NA))
```

I want to replace 0 values with NA in every row until a positive value is encountered (no negative values in dataset). In addition to that I want to replace all values if their ending  are all zeros leaving first 0 in place after last positive value. etc 5,0,0,0 -> 5,0,NA,NA

Provided example data with desiredresult. I was trying approach something like this, but there would need to be 5+ conditions to cover it all. Is there a better way to do this? Maybe with data.table?

```
dat$B[dat$B == 0 & (dat$C!=0 | dat$D!=0)] <- NA
dat$C[dat$C == 0 & dat$D!=0 & is.na(dat$B)] <- NA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `data.table`-package, you could approach this as follows:

```
cols <- names(dat)[2:6]
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[, (cols) := {x <- unlist(.SD);
                        x[cumsum(x)==0] <- NA;
                        l <- c(tail(cumsum(rev(x)),-1),1) == 0;
                        x[rev(l)] <- NA;
                        names(x) <- cols;
                        as.list(x)},
           by = A]
```

you get:

```
> dat
       A  B  C D  E  F
1: name1 NA NA 4  1  4
2: name2  1  0 4  0 NA
3: name3 NA  5 0 NA NA
```

---

The same kind of thinking, but then with base R:

```
dl <- as.data.frame(t(dat[,-1]))

idx1 <- cumsum(dl) == 0
idx2 <- sapply(dl, function(x) {
  l <- c(tail(cumsum(rev(x)),-1),1) == 0
  l[is.na(l)] <- FALSE
  rev(l)
})

dl[idx1 | idx2] <- NA
dat[,-1] <- t(dl)
```

which will get you the same result:

```
> dat
      A  B  C D  E  F
1 name1 NA NA 4  1  4
2 name2  1  0 0  4  0
3 name3 NA  5 0 NA NA
```

---

**New example data:**

```
dat <- data.frame(A=c("name1", "name2", "name3"), 
                  B=c(0,1,0), C=c(0,0,5), D=c(4,0,0), E=c(1,4,0), F=c(4,0,0) )
```

Comment: @user2941942 I've updated my answer, the previous solution didn't work well when there were more zeros between positives (see also the includen new example data)

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
#Apply the first rule: convert 0 to NA until we find  a non negative
res1<-t(apply(dat[,-1], 1, function(x) {
  xc <- cumsum(x) #cumulative sum
  x[xc==0]<-NA #NA where cumulative sum iz 0
  x
}))

# Apply the second rule
res2<-t(apply(res1, 1, function(x) {
  xc <- cumsum(rev(x)) #reverse the sum
  xc<-c(tail(xc,-1),1) # shift the sum
  res<-rev(x) #reverse the vector
  res[xc==0]<-NA
  rev(res)
}))

#Reconstruct the data frame
cbind(data.frame(name=dat[,1]),res2)

#   name  B  C D  E  F
#1 name1 NA NA 4  1  4
#2 name2  1  0 4  0 NA
#3 name3 NA  5 0 NA NA
```